# VBA - Business day-1

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that give me the business day in column B.  However, I need column A to have a the previous days date.  Eg: A should have B-1.  If its a weekend it should have the date of Friday.  please assist.

```
With Worksheets("Majors")
.Range("B3").ClearContents
Select Case Month(Now)
Case 2: mMax = IIf(Year(Now) Mod 4 = 0, 29, 28)
Case 4, 6, 9, 11: mMax = 30
Case Else: mMax = 31
End Select
B = 2
For mDay = 1 To 31
wNam = WeekdayName(Weekday(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), mDay)), True,  1)
If Not wNam = "Sat" And Not wNam = "Sun" Then
    B = B + 1
    Cells(B, 2) = (DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), mDay))
End If
If mDay = mMax Then Exit For
Next mDay

End With
```

Comment: as a side note, you can refactor your `Select Case` statement with just one simple line: `mMax = Day(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Now(), 0))`. You can also refactor your loop with `For mDay = 1 to mMax` and then delete the `If mDay = mMax Then Exit For`

Answer (score 2):

This gives the working day before of date in A1:

```
mDate = CDate(Range("A1"))
AnteWorkDay = DateAdd("d", -1, mDate)
Do While Weekday(AnteWorkDay) = vbSunday Or Weekday(AnteWorkDay) = vbSaturday
    AnteWorkDay = DateAdd("d", -1, AnteWorkDay)
Loop
MsgBox AnteWorkDay
```